# MailChimp integration Error code 501 - Unsupported request - PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, mailchimp

Below is my code to add contact to the mailchimp. I am getting mailchimp api key and list id from the env file in laravel. Also $data involves all the input.

```
        $apiKey = env('MAILCHIMP_APIKEY');
        $listId = env('MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID');
        $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apiKey);

        $mailChimpdata = array(
            'apikey'        => $apiKey,
            'email_address' => $data['email'],
            'status'        => $data['status'],
            'merge_fields'  => array(
                'FNAME'     => $data['firstname'],
                'LNAME'     => $data['lastname']
            )
        );

        $json_data = json_encode($mailChimpdata);

        $ch = curl_init();
        $memberId = md5(strtolower($data['email']));
      
        $url = 'https://us19.admin.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listId . '/members/' . $memberId; 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);       
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

But I am getting this below error

```
HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 334
Expires: Wed, 07 Apr 2021 08:49:45 GMT
Date: Wed, 07 Apr 2021 08:49:45 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: _abck=471ED28A26F6757CE57AC9E4318E7BD6~-1~YAAQHdcLF/keKqt4AQAASPOFqwWS/EeAKXso+2igviRTfIMw3pqbDMndhfZPfoX+eQn3Iv8iqfbogtNFmkU4lRDRQLdAWAYBhq2oOhDTiK ▶
Set-Cookie: bm_sz=5CBD698E96AC9E2B62898990FF45E196~YAAQHdcLF/oeKqt4AQAASPOFqwsLVm8fKmxtToeWU99vCUWske+XMuRtEjiCpzXhPE5xe8jGoh6EfYe8WG6zjMaaI2jPZos0gb2ER9jykveOE ▶

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Unsupported Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Unsupported Request</H1>
PUT to http&#58;&#47;&#47;us19&#46;admin&#46;mailchimp&#46;com&#47;3&#46;0&#47;lists&#47;applevendor&#47;members&#47;b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452 not supported.<P> 
Reference&#32;&#35;8&#46;1dd70b17&#46;1617785385&#46;68d39e
</BODY></HTML>
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Mailchimp documentation](https://metamug.com/article/api-integration/php-mailchimp-api-add-subscriber-email.html) they use URL to **add contact**

```php
"https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/$list_id/members/"
```

but you have

```php
"https://us19.admin.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/$listId/members/$memberId"
```

with `$memberId`. I guess that `id` is their internal identificator.

Comment: Now it gives 403 Forbidden. - "status":403,"detail":"The API key provided is linked to datacenter 'us1'",

Comment: Your key contains `-usSomeNumber` so use it in request URL too. For example key `xxxxx-us19` should use `https://us19.api.mailchimp.com` and key `xxxxx-us20` should use `https://us20.api.mailchimp.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this topic is still relevant but here is my method using php / Guzzle:

```
$client = new Client();
$client->request('PUT', 'https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}, 
[
  'json' => [
    'email_address' => $email, 
    'status_if_new' => "unsubscribed",
            ],
  'headers' => [
    "Authorization" => "Basic YOUR_API_KEY"
  ]
]);
```

subscriber_hash => hash MD5